# How I call _email in a container ? in Flutter Android pp

Tags: variables, flutter, dart, jwt

I need to display  J**WT token values in a Container** . I trying many ways return the value ,declare a global variable but doesn't work . when I declare a global variable it send NULL value.  How Can I do that ?
I developed my app using **Flutter**

my code

```
 class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen> {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

String _email;

  final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLoginStatus();



  }
   checkLoginStatus() async {
    sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if(sharedPreferences.getString("token") == null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);

  }
var token = sharedPreferences.getString("token");
var payload = Jwt.parseJwt(token);
print(payload);
print(payload["email"]);
 _email = payload["email"];
  print("Hello world");
  print(_email);
return _email;

   }
```

I want to send that email value to container.

My container section is here

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[200],
      child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
          sharedPreferences.clear();
          sharedPreferences.commit();
          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Login()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        },
    ),
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, .9),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: 330,
                color: Colors.blueAccent[200],
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 10,
                right: 30,
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.settings, //setting Icon
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 90,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                      child: Icon(Icons.tag_faces),
                    )
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  ),
                  Text(
                     _email,  // here I call that variable
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        fontSize: 20,fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

add null check

```
Text(
   _email == null || _email.isEmpty ?'Loading (or) nil' : _email,
   style: TextStyle(
       color: Colors.white,
       fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
       fontSize: 20,fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
       textAlign: TextAlign.center),
```

Comment: in that code check null if it is null display Loading (or) nil bud not display the value . I want to display the value bro ..

Comment: Call setState while initializing _email